# What is wrong with my pi calculator?

Tags: java

I'm using Wallis' method to calculate pi, and I think I did it right. At least I *thought* I did anyway. I think the problem (output is 0)has to do with rounding and remainders, though I can't be sure. Here's the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WallisPi {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int a = 2;
        int b = 3;
        int c = 1;
        int pi = 0;
        double acc = 0.0;

        int n = scan.nextInt();
        scan.close();

        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
            pi = (2 / 3) * c;
            if (a > b) {
                b += 2;
            } else {
                a += 2;
            }
            c = a / b;
        }

        pi *= 4;

        System.out.println("The approximation of pi is " + pi + ".");
        acc = Math.PI - pi;
        System.out.println("It is " + acc + " off.");
    }
}
```

Since posting this I've made some changes to the code, though it's still not quite functional. I get 2.666..., so there's something else at work here as well.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WallisPi {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        double a = 2.0;
        double b = 3.0;
        double c = 1.0;
        double pi = 0;
        double acc = 0.0;

        int n = scan.nextInt();
        scan.close();

        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
            pi = (2.0 / 3.0) * c;
            if (a > b) {
                b += 2;
            } else {
                a += 2;
            }
            c = a / b;
        }

        pi *= 4;

        System.out.println("The approximation of pi is " + pi + ".");
        acc = Math.PI - pi;
        System.out.println("It is " + acc + " off.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please describe what you consider "the problem".

Comment: What isn't working? Errors? Exceptions? Incorrect output?

Comment: change `2/3` to `2.0/3.0` and `int` to `double`

Comment: hes using `int pi=0` use `double` or `float`

Comment: You have to repeatedly multiply the fractions with the first fraction 2/1.

Comment: Oh, pardon me. The problem is that pi was said to be 0 in my output. Since putting up this code I did change everything to double. It's technically working, but I get something around 2.6, not what I want.

Comment: @Andorino you already have a good and working answer, so what's the point of posting "updated" code? Just accept it ;)

Comment: OK, I saw the 0 soon enough, and the missing infinite product and the integer division made that question moot.

Comment: @MightyPork I was ninja'd while updating :)

Comment: @Andorino Kindly look at my answer, and see how this infinite product has to be calculated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int a=2;
int b=3;
double pi=2;
for(int i=0;i<=n;i++){
   pi *= (double)a/(double)b;
  if(a>b){
    b+=2;
  } else {
    a+=2;
  }
}
pi*=2;
```

Using n = 4000 yields 3.141200

---

Here's the whole program, fixed:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WallisPi {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scan.nextInt();
        scan.close();

        double pi = 2;
        int a = 2;
        int b = 3;

        for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++){
            pi *= (double) a / (double) b;
            if (a > b) {
                b += 2;
            } else {
                a += 2;
            }
        }

        pi *= 2;

        double acc = Math.PI - pi;

        System.out.println("The approximation of pi is " + pi + ".");
        System.out.println("It is " + acc + " off.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Pi is fine, but the accuracy is all funny-like.

Comment: With 100.000.000 iterations, I get accuracy 1.5711289602649003E-8. Looks quite good to me.

Comment: @Andorino Perhaps you study a little math, and then you complain - but Wallis is dead a long time anyway.

Comment: Is that how it's supposed to be? I would have thought it to be smaller than that. I guess I need to up my math skills.

Answer (score 0):

Since your varibles are `int`s, all your divisions are integer divisions, omitting the fraction (and preserving only the whole part of the result). For accurate results, you should define your variables as `double`s:

```
double a=2;
double b=3;
double c=1;
double pi=0;
```

Comment: This is the obvious bug, but there is something else rotten in the code, since the result converges to `2.66666`, not PI.